# css horizontal dropdown menu wordpress shown behind flash video embed

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu, flash-video

Here is the site:

http://ivideez.com/

As you can see my dropdowns are being hidden behind the video; how do I get then to dropdown OVER the video.

What do I add to css?  i've tried overflow, position, z-index, I'm stuck, any advice? I'd prefer if cross-broswer capable answer.

Comment: Have you tried adding a z-index to the menu's styling to bring it above the embed? Try adding something like z-index: 1000; to the main dropdown element's style definition.

Comment: Look up FOUC, which stands for Flash Of Unstyled Content. This is potentially a path to solution for you. Hope that helps! Nash

Comment: Works fine in the latest Firefox. What browser are you seeing the issues in?

Comment: it does work in firefox yet not in chrome or IE, thanks guys so far!

Comment: Works fine for me in latest Chrome a Safari. As an aside, 160 requests, 6.5MB ~30 seconds to load on a 6Mb/s connection - I'd work on paring that down a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Use wmode property of embed to transparent as like bellow :-

```
wmode=transparent
```

I hope it will helps..!!

PS

For more details :- [Refer to here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html)

Answer (score -1):

i had same  problem once and i solved it by applying z-index to main container. try giving the z-index value to parent container that holds the dropdown menu instead of directly giving it to the .. Also give z-index to flash video whose value should be smaller..